# MapBox pins don't render

Tags: reactjs, mapbox, mapbox-gl, react-map-gl, mapbox-marker

I am following a guide step by step building a MapBox map component with markers on it. I am using React for this, and unlike the guide, I am using typescript.

I am using the `react-map-gl` as well. I got to the point of rendering markers, and unlike the guide, my markers simply don't render. I've gone to the `react-map-gl` documentation and it seems that I am doing everything correctly. I am getting no errors as well not in my IDE or in the console, yet no makrers.

Everything else works fine. The map opens, and it is indeed centered around where all the pins are (according to the data).

This is my component:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import ReactMapGL, { Marker } from "react-map-gl";
import getCenter from "geolib/es/getCenter";

function Map({ searchResults }: { searchResults: Array<any> }) {
  const [selectedLocation, setSelectedLocation] = useState();

  const coords = searchResults.map((result) => ({
    latitude: result.lat,
    longitude: result.long,
  }));

  const center = getCenter(coords);

  const [viewport, setViewport] = useState({
    latitude: center ? center.latitude : 0,
    longitude: center ? center.longitude : 0,
    zoom: 8,
  });

  console.log(selectedLocation);

  return (
    <ReactMapGL
      mapStyle="mapbox://styles/levanter/cld8rfy27001w01oc8m0sl8pk"
      mapboxAccessToken={process.env.mapbox_key}
      style={{
        width: "100%",
        height: "100%",
      }}
      initialViewState={{ ...viewport }}
      onMove={(evt) => setViewport(evt.viewState)}
    >
      {searchResults.map((result) => {
        return (
          <div key={result.long}>
            <Marker
              longitude={result.long}
              latitude={result.lat}
              //   anchor="bottom"
              //   offset={[-20, -10]}
            >
              <p
                className="cursor-pointer text-2xl animate-bounce"
                onClick={() => setSelectedLocation(result)}
              >
                
              </p>
            </Marker>
          </div>
        );
      })}
    </ReactMapGL>
  );
}

export default Map;
```

And this is the dummy data I am working with:

```
[
  {
    "img": "https://links.papareact.com/xqj",
    "location": "Private room in center of London",
    "title": "Stay at this spacious Edwardian House",
    "description": "1 guest · 1 bedroom · 1 bed · 1.5 shared bthrooms · Wifi · Kitchen · Free parking · Washing Machine",
    "star": 4.73,
    "price": "£30 / night",
    "total": "£117 total",
    "long": -0.0022275,
    "lat": 51.5421655
  },
  {
    "img": "https://links.papareact.com/hz2",
    "location": "Private room in center of London",
    "title": "Independant luxury studio apartment",
    "description": "2 guest · 3 bedroom · 1 bed · 1.5 shared bthrooms · Wifi · Kitchen",
    "star": 4.3,
    "price": "£40 / night",
    "total": "£157 total",
    "long": -0.095091,
    "lat": 51.48695
  },
  {
    "img": "https://links.papareact.com/uz7",
    "location": "Private room in center of London",
    "title": "London Studio Apartments",
    "description": "4 guest · 4 bedroom · 4 bed · 2 bathrooms · Free parking · Washing Machine",
    "star": 3.8,
    "price": "£35 / night",
    "total": "£207 total",
    "long": -0.135638,
    "lat": 51.521916
  },
  {
    "img": "https://links.papareact.com/6as",
    "location": "Private room in center of London",
    "title": "30 mins to Oxford Street, Excel London",
    "description": "1 guest · 1 bedroom · 1 bed · 1.5 shared bthrooms · Wifi · Kitchen · Free parking · Washing Machine",
    "star": 4.1,
    "price": "£55 / night",
    "total": "£320 total",
    "long": -0.069961,
    "lat": 51.472618
  },
  {
    "img": "https://links.papareact.com/xhc",
    "location": "Private room in center of London",
    "title": "Spacious Peaceful Modern Bedroom",
    "description": "3 guest · 1 bedroom · 1 bed · 1.5 shared bthrooms · Wifi · Free parking · Dry Cleaning",
    "star": 5.0,
    "price": "£60 / night",
    "total": "£450 total",
    "long": -0.08472,
    "lat": 51.510794
  },
  {
    "img": "https://links.papareact.com/pro",
    "location": "Private room in center of London",
    "title": "The Blue Room In London",
    "description": "2 guest · 1 bedroom · 1 bed · 1.5 shared bthrooms · Wifi · Washing Machine",
    "star": 4.23,
    "price": "£65 / night",
    "total": "£480 total",
    "long": -0.094116,
    "lat": 51.51401
  },
  {
    "img": "https://links.papareact.com/8w2",
    "location": "Private room in center of London",
    "title": "5 Star Luxury Apartment",
    "description": "3 guest · 1 bedroom · 1 bed · 1.5 shared bthrooms · Wifi · Kitchen · Free parking · Washing Machine",
    "star": 3.85,
    "price": "£90 / night",
    "total": "£650 total",
    "long": -0.109889,
    "lat": 51.521245
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding thwe following solved my issue:

`import "mapbox-gl/dist/mapbox-gl.css";`